# Add VBA code to a MS Word document using Perl

Tags: vba, perl, ms-word

I have a Perl script that can define and write MS Word VBA according to the user's input.

How can I make the Perl script open Word and add the VBA code into its code data base?

Answer (score 2):

You can do that by accessing the `VBProject` property of the document. However, with recent versions of Microsoft Office, you will likely get:

```
OLE exception from "Microsoft Word":

Programmatic access to Visual Basic Project is not trusted.
```

See [You may receive an run-time error when you programmatically allow access](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/813969) KB article for more information.

Or, you can try to do it the primitive way by sending keystrokes to Word using [Win32::GuiTest](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Win32::GuiTest).